# How to programm AVR ATmega48 in TQFP32 soldered onboard?

Tags: avr, tqfp

I have a board (actually - many of them) with ATmega48PA (TQFP32) soldered in and no ISP connector. Some of the ISP lines are even not routed.

I used [Hobbyking programmer](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/atmel-atmega-socket-firmware-flashing-tool.html?___store=en_us) to connect to the processor in the past:

[image]

I have had two of them. And I felt my self comfortable with it. However I broke one today and find out that it is not possible to order this connector again.

Now I desperately need any solution which could help me. Processors are already soldered on the boards and it will be a nightmare if I will need to unsolder and flash it separately.

Is there any ideas?

Comment: Fix the broken programmer or make a new one.  Looks like a piece of plastic and some Pogo pins, maybe P50's.  Probably not something you can *reliably* crank out on a hobby 3d printer but with hand fitting you probably can make one that will work for a while.   Or solder right to the pins if you only need to do a few.

Answer (score 2):

[image: micro grabber test clips]  [image]

Micro grabber clips have come in handy for me a few times.  Attaching them will be slower than using a fixture, but certainly easier than unsoldering parts. They're fragile so you might want to buy a few extra.

Here's one source: https://www.newark.com/pomona/72902-2/test-clip-1position/dp/74K0031

Comment: Those are 20+ USD apiece. Not really hobbyist territory.